# Automate Sourcing Data from Multiple .GDB's to a Single "Template" MXD using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, mxd

I have a single "template" MXD I'm using and repeatedly resourcing the layers to newly created features that always fall within the same 4 geodatabases. The new features all follow the same nomenclature except for a unique identifier number at the end.

Is this task possible to automate in ModelBuilder?

If so, can someone point me to material that can teach me how to do this?

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 2):

ModelBuilder could be part of an automation workflow to do this but it would need to use a Python script tool written with ArcPy functions to switch the Layer data sources.

Consequently, I think you would be better to keep ModelBuilder out of this loop and do it all using ArcPy.

Comment: Do you know of a tutorial that explains how to accomplish this? I have very little Python knowledge.

Comment: It will be in the ArcGIS documentation. Search on ArcPy and data sources.  Q&As with code to learn from can be found by doing the same search here.